# How to read text one line at a time from a file, and assign the text to a variable in Clojure

Tags: clojure, io

I want to open a large XML file in Clojure, process the text line per line then dump a selection of strings into a work file.

I am totally new to this so for now I just want to be able to (1) read a file, and (2) assign the selection to a variable. I will be working with large XML files so slurping is not an option.

Anyway, I'm using this code I got from a tutorial. Whenever I execute it in REPL, it prints out the text contained in my file, but seems to fail with creating the variable str1(unresolved symbol error).

Here's the code:

```
(defn readfile []
  (let [str1    ;; I want the text inside the text file to fill this variable
        (with-open [rdr (io/reader "resources/loremipsum.txt")]
          (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr)))] str1))
(readfile)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why you want to process a large XML file line-by-line? Generally you can't assume that tags and contents are contained in the same line and that determines that parsers follow a "stream of tags" approach, but maybe in your case is different and that changes the suggestions.

Comment: Originally plan was to convert the XML to CSV, but LOAD INTO couldn't handle the duplicate tags so I had to brute force reading the file line by line to get the values. Also need to do a some of sorting and what not, so reinventing the wheel seemed like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

the code you have listed here is correct, did something get changed in copying and pasting it in?

```
user=> (require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
nil

(defn readfile []
  (let [str1 (with-open [rdr (io/reader "lorum-lispsum")]
               (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr)))] 
    str1))
#'user/readfile

user=> (readfile)
["let lambda bind lambda let lambda"]
```

the patern `(reduce conj...)` is often more easily written with the `into` function.

```
(defn readfile []
  (let [str1 (with-open [rdr (io/reader "lorum-lispsum")]
               (into [] (line-seq rdr)))] 
    str1))
```

and since the effect of the `into` here is both to make it a vector and to pull the entire file into memory simultaneously it could be replaced with a call to `vec`

```
(defn readfile []
  (let [str1 (with-open [rdr (io/reader "lorum-lispsum")]
               (vec (line-seq rdr)))] 
    str1))
```

since you also mention that not storing the whole file in memory is a goal, we may want to rearrange things to keep the file open while the sequence is processed as a lazy sequence

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn process-a-line [line]
  :your-code-here)

(defn the-main-part-of-my-program [lazy-sequence-of-lines]
  (dorun (map process-a-line)))

(defn readfile []
  (let [str1 (with-open [rdr (io/reader "lorum-lispsum")]
               (line-seq rdr))] 
    (the-main-part-of-my-program str1)))
```

Comment: I believe the value of the string is only available within the scope of the LET body, as confirmed by the latest post from Lee.

You example using a lazy sequence processing looks promising. I think it is exactly what is needed in my case, with the files that I need to work on and the volume of data that I have to sift through.

Comment: btw, smart move with the lorum-lispsum. appreciate it :)

Comment: your example already properly places all uses of the `str1` name already correctly places the symbol within the scope of the let. it gives that symbol a value within the `[   ]` section then places the same value into the return position of the body of the let binding. The body of a let expression is everything after the `[  ]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to deal with xml in clojure, I'd recommend clojure.data.zip. Here's a quick example:

```
(require '[clojure.xml :as xml])
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])
(require '[clojure.data.zip.xml :as zf])
(import '[java.io ByteArrayInputStream])
(with-open [in-stream (ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes "
<xml>
  <test>something</test>
  <fish>dog</fish>
  <test>something else</test>
</xml>"))]
  (let [parsed (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse in-stream))]
    (zf/xml-> parsed :xml :test zf/text)))
```

It will produce a lazy sequence of the selector provided. It's quite often a really nice way to work with XML, and may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings declared within a `let` are only visible within the `let` body. Since your `readfile` function returns the lines of the file you can create a var and assign the result of calling the function to it:

```
(def lines (readfile))
```

Comment: Yes, you care correct. Precisely why the value of str1 is no longer available.